Finitely generated projective modules over Noetherian endomorphism ring
Let $\mathcal A$ be a locally Noetherian Grothendieck abelian category and $M\in \mathcal A$ be a Noetherian object. Set $B:=\text{End}_{\mathcal A}(M)$. Let $B$-mod be the category of finitely generated right $B$-modules. Then, is it true that $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal A}(M,-): \text{add}_{\mathcal A}(M)\to \text{proj}(B\text{-mod})$ is an equivalence of categories?
Here, $\text{add}_{\mathcal A}(M)$ denotes the collection of all objects in $\mathcal A$ which are direct summands of finite direct sum of copies of $M$, and $\text{proj}(B\text{-mod})$ are the finitely generated projective right $B$-modules.

This is true for $\mathcal{A}$ an idempotent complete additive category.

@FernandoMuro: thanks ... could you please give me a reference?

Where are you stuck? For example, did you try to prove that the functor is essentially surjective? Seems like a basic exercise.

Just to point out, $B$ may not be a noetherian ring.
